# JQuery Breaks Outside Specific div tag in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

This works fine, the text area works as expected.

```html
<div id="frm_field_727-718-0_container" class="frm_form_field form-field  form-group frm_top_container col-lg-6 activity_section frm1 frm_field_727_container">

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".flextextArea").on("keydown keyup", function(){
        this.style.height = "32px";
        this.style.height = (this.scrollHeight) + "px"; 
    });
});
</script>

    <label for="field_7u7u3-0" class="frm_primary_label control-label">Paragraph
        <span class="frm_required"></span>
        
    </label>
     <textarea name="item_meta[718][0][727]" id="field_7u7u3-0" rows="1"  class="flextextArea form-control"></textarea>
    
    
</div>
```

But it breaks if I move the script to the head section eg:

```html
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".flextextArea").on("keydown keyup", function(){
        this.style.height = "32px";
        this.style.height = (this.scrollHeight) + "px"; 
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<div id="frm_field_727-718-0_container" class="frm_form_field form-field  form-group frm_top_container col-lg-6 activity_section frm1 frm_field_727_container">

    <label for="field_7u7u3-0" class="frm_primary_label control-label">Paragraph
        <span class="frm_required"></span>
    </label>
    
     <textarea name="item_meta[718][0][727]" id="field_7u7u3-0" rows="1" data-sectionid="718" data-invmsg="Paragraph is invalid" class="flextextArea form-control"></textarea>
    
    
</div>
```

I've been messing with this, I also tried to add all the classes in place of .flextextArea. I hope this makes sense, I've searched here but I'm not quite understanding the answers to similar questions.

Comment: Script should be referenced closer to the closing `body` tag where possible. There’s a reason for this. Mainly because the content before it needs to be loaded in the DOM before your code can get/manipulate it. If you can’t move it from the `head` use [ready](https://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Answer (score 0):

adding:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and placing the script closer to the closing body tag solves it. Weird because I haven't had to add the script src before for other jQuery on the same page.